# No permissions to upload files after installing Wordpress on EC2 - Amazon Tutorial

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-ec2

quite a noob here. Was just able to install a Wordpress following this Amazon tutorial:

[Tutorial: Hosting a WordPress Blog with Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html)

The thing is, that I cant upload any images. 
Actually the error I get is:

> Cant create "Upload" directory. Does the parent directory have persmission?

*(not exactly these words as my wp is in portuguese)*

I can do everything via FTP *(that I installed using this tutorial: [The White Way - How to set up WordPress on Amazon EC2](http://stephen-white.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/how-to-set-up-wordpress-on-amazon-ec2_31.html))*.

What I'm trying to learn:
**How can I change permissions so that I may upload/create files and folders via Wordpress?**

### Thanks a lot!

**Solution:** *OK guys what worked for me was: set wp-content and recursively all subfolders and files to permission 777: then I was able to upload. After that I went back to 755 and it continued functioning.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm usually the 755 permission should fix the issue. Maybe check out that folders inside wp-content have also a 755 permission. If this doesn't fix the problem, create a folder called 'uploads' under wp-content and make sure this folder has also a 755 permission.

Comment: Hi @ashish67 also did what you instructed. I created a upload folder with 755 permission (and set it to recursivly change permission to 755 for all subfolders) then I got a message that "No permission to create /2014/01" folder. Then I created that on my own. And tried uploading a file. And now the error is: Couldn't move the uploaded file to the .../uploads/2014/01 folder" even though the error says its a permission issue, can it be another thing?

Comment: Hey just to give closure. I edited my post with the correct answer derriving from your counsels ashish67.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your wp-content folder has a 755 permission so that wordpress can create an upload directory inside Wp-content folder. You should be able to change the permission of WP-content through FTP.

Comment: hey, thanks. Just checked and permission is already 755. Any other idea?